# Show list of commits since last pull

Tags: node.js, git

i have a local git repos. Now is want to have a list with all commit hash since the last pull. So a possible to list them.

hfsjkhgdfjkhgjkhfgjk
gfegwgwwgewgeregeerg
ewgetwgetgtgtgttewgt
gwtgwgtgtrwgtrwtggrw

Something like this. I also need the list of files from each commit and the commit message. I need it to use it in a nodejs Page to display it in a user frontend.

See you
Rogoit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from the question which set of commits you want to see.

1. Assuming that origin has not changed since your last pull (which would probably require that you're in a single developer environment), and that you want to see *local* commits that aren't on origin, you could use `git log origin..master` or even `git log origin..`.
2. Assuming that you want to see what will change if you pull from origin, try this:

   ```
   git fetch origin
   git diff origin/master
   ```

   `git diff` has many options that will allow you to tailor its output.  Hopefully you can make this produce what you need.

Comment: Hi,

no this shows all commits and not only the last 2 since my last pull. I only want to see the incomming commits since my last pull.

See you
Rogo

Comment: Sourcetree can show the newest commits. So there must be a way to do it.

Comment: Is that second option closer to what you need?

Comment: git fetch && git log --graph --boundary --left-right --cherry-pick --decorate HEAD..FETCH_HEAD

Comment: This is the solution

git fetch && git log --boundary --left-right --cherry-pick --decorate --pretty=format:%H HEAD..FETCH_HEAD

Comment: Nice.  You should add it as an answer and accept it.  Explain what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking `git pull`, try a `git fetch` followed by `git diff master..origin/master`.

Then follow this up with a `git pull`.